# Ionic 3 plugin_not_installed

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Estou com um aplicativo IONIC 3 rodando normalmente quando executo: `ionic cordova run android`.

O problema é quando executo `ionic cordova run android --prod` da o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quando você vai instalar os plugins pelo Ionic você está usando a flag **--save**?
Outra coisa que pode estar acontecendo é um plugin não estar disponível na versão da sua plataforma. Por exemplo, no config.xml eu estava usando a versão 6.1.2 do android, e no plugin de camera, ele disse que o plugin só funcionava em versões > 6.3.0.

Tive que atualizar a versão do meu android: **ionic cordova platform upgrade android@6.3.0**

**Nota:** O @ após 'android' foi para especificar a versão que eu queria instalar.